# How can I rewrite this ID selector as a class or general selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

The following selector allows me to display four tabs, but I would like a generic code for displaying 5, 6, and more. Is there is another way to write this CSS code for any number of tabs? (I would prefer a CSS-only solution).

```css
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked>
  <label for="tab1">Codepen</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab2">Dribbble</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab3">Dropbox</label>
    
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab4">Drupal</label>
  
   <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs">
  <label for="tab5">Drupal</label>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLbvr2gh/) with a full demo.

Comment: Hmmmm, I might be completely wrong but I don't think this is possible WITHOUT JavaScript... Any reason why you can't use JS?

Comment: Because i think my page can load faster with a full css solution, if i have no solution, i'll use javascript, but if it's possible, i would like a full css...

Comment: Vanilla JS is extremely fast and I can think of a couple of ways using it that would be good solution here... I sincerely doubt you'll notice much of an impact on speed at all. Like I said, I don't think this is possible in CSS-only...

Comment: you have to add everything manually.

Comment: Is a CSS preprocessor like LESS/SCSS an option? You could write a `mixin` to iteratively build out n number of levels. It isn't super clean but it wouldn't involve using JS on the page.

[This example uses SCSS](https://jsfiddle.net/itopizarro/kz594ktz/) but it should be portable to LESS with minimal effort.

Answer (score 1):

You may rewrite your html a bit to achieve this:

```
<input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" class="tabs-radio" checked>
<label for="tab1">Codepen</label>
<section id="content1" class="tabs-content">
....
</section>
<input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" class="tabs-radio">
....
```

Then you can simply do:

```
.tabs-radio:checked + * + .tabs-content {
  display: block;
}
```

Only problem is positioning of labels/blocks: one of them should be absolutely positioned

Answer (score 0):

Although you said JS wasn't ideal, I thought I'd post a JS solution for you to take a look at since you said you'd resort to it if need be...

```js
function contentShow() {
  var tabs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    if (tabs[i].checked == true) {
      var tabid = tabs[i].id;
      var tabstripped = tabid.replace('tab','');
      var contentid = "content"+ tabstripped;
      var sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
      for(var i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
          sections[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      document.getElementById(contentid).style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 14px/1 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #555;
  background: #eee;
}

h1 {
  padding: 50px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  min-width: 640px;
  max-width: 1600px;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fff;
}

section {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

input {
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 -1px;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #bbb;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

label:before {
  font-family: fontawesome;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/*label[for*='1']:before { content: '\f1cb'; }
label[for*='2']:before { content: '\f17d'; }
label[for*='3']:before { content: '\f16b'; }
label[for*='4']:before { content: '\f1a9'; }*/

label:hover {
  color: #888;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top: 2px solid orange;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
 /* label {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  label:before {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}*/

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  label {
    padding: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Responsive CSS Tabs</h1>

<main>
  
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab1">Tab 1</label>
    
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab2">Tab 2</label>
    
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab3">Tab 3</label>
    
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab4">Tab 4</label>
  
   <input id="tab5" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab5">Tab 5</label>
  
  <input id="tab6" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab6">Tab 6</label>
  
  <input id="tab7" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab7">Tab 7</label>
  
  <input id="tab8" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab8">Tab 8</label>
  
  <input id="tab9" type="radio" name="tabs" onclick="contentShow()">
  <label for="tab9">Tab 9</label>
    
  <section id="content1">
   <p hidden>yoo man</p>
    <p>
      Content 1
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content2">
    <p>
      Content 2
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content3">
    <p>
      Content 3
    </p>
  </section>
    
  <section id="content4">
    <p>
      Content 4
    </p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="content5">
    <p>
      Content 5
    </p>
  </section>
    
    <section id="content6">
    <p>
      Content 6
    </p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="content7">
    <p>
      Content 7
    </p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="content8">
    <p>
      Content 8
    </p>
  </section>
  
  <section id="content9">
    <p>
      Content 9
    </p>
  </section>
    
    
</main>
```

As you can see, clicking on a radio button triggers a function...

What the function does is loop through each instance of the radio button (I've simply used `input` in this example). I then see if the radio button is checked (which it will be). I then get the corresponding content `section` according to the id # of the radio button that's been checked and display that - whilst also hiding any other content `sections` that might be visible from a previous click.

Using this way, you can add as many radio buttons / content sections as you like.

Here's a fiddle too: https://jsfiddle.net/LLbvr2gh/2/